# Create a database to store module name along with it parent_module_id

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

Okay i have a table, where i store names of all the modules or programs, somewhat like this

```
+----+----------------+
|id  |module          |
+----+----------------+
|1   |node js         |
+----+----------------+
|2   |python          |
+----+----------------+
|3   |angular         |
+----+----------------+
|4   |ionic           |
+----+----------------+
|5   |tensorflow      |
+----+----------------+
|6   |jupyter notebook|
+----+----------------+
```

Now i want to store parent module of all the modules such as we need to have `nodejs` installed to start using `ionic` or for `tensorflow` we need to have `python`. Now i had two i included a column named `parent_id` which was `foreign_key` referencing `id` of the same table.

```
+----+----------------+----------+
|id  |module          |parent_id |
+----+----------------+----------+
|1   |node js         |null      |
+----+----------------+----------+
|2   |python          |null      |
+----+----------------+----------+
|3   |angular         |1         |
+----+----------------+----------+
|4   |ionic           |1         |
+----+----------------+----------+
|5   |tensorflow      |2         |
+----+----------------+----------+
|6   |jupyter notebook|2         |
+----+----------------+----------+
```

This helped me give parents the option of having multiple child, like nodejs had two childs angular and ionic.

I am using sequelize and i have setup the association as any regular association.

```
//--------- module.model.js------------//
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Module = sequelize.define('Module', {
  }, {
    timestamps: false
  });
  module.associate = function(models) {
    Module.hasMany(Module, {
      foreignKey: 'parent_id',
    });
    Module.belongsTo(Module, {
      foreignKey: 'parent_id',
    });
  };
  return Module;
};

//--------------- index.js-------------//
const models = require('./models');  //module.models.js

async function start() {
  let modules = await models.Module.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: models.Module
    }]
  });
  console.log(modules);
}
start();
```

Output is somewhat like this:

```
[{id: 1, module: 'node js', Module: [
    {id: 3, module: 'angular'},
    {id: 4, module: 'ionic'}
  ]},
 {id: 2, module: 'python', Module: [
    {id: 5, module: 'tensorflow'},
    {id: 6, module: 'jupyter notebook'}
  ]},
 {id: 3, module: 'angular', Module: []},
 {id: 4, module: 'ionic', Module: []},
 {id: 5, module: 'tensorflow', Module: []},
 {id: 6, module: 'jupyter notebook', Module: []}]
```

which was quite expected, but i want to get the parent modules array inside the child entiries, somewhat like this:

```
[{id: 1, module: 'node js', Module: []},
 {id: 2, module: 'python', Module: []},
 {id: 3, module: 'angular', Module: [
    {id: 1, module: 'node js'}
  ]},
 {id: 4, module: 'ionic', Module: [
    {id: 1, module: 'node js'},
  ]},
 {id: 5, module: 'tensorflow', Module: [
    {id: 2, module: 'python'},
  ]},
 {id: 6, module: 'jupyter notebook', Module: [
    {id: 2, module: 'python'},
  ]}]
```

I know i can change the `parent_id` column to `child id` map modules in an opposite way but that excludes the possibility of a parent having multiple child and will show only one child per parent.

```
+----+----------------+----------+
|id  |module          |child_id  |
+----+----------------+----------+
|1   |node js         |3         |
+----+----------------+----------+
|2   |python          |5         |
+----+----------------+----------+
|3   |angular         |null      |
+----+----------------+----------+
|4   |ionic           |null      |
+----+----------------+----------+
|5   |tensorflow      |null      |
+----+----------------+----------+
|6   |jupyter notebook|null      |
+----+----------------+----------+
```

So how can achieve the desired output and what modification do need to make in the associations or the entire table structure by including a third table which will have two foreing key referring the same table, somewhat like this but this doesn't look so conventional, or to be honest i have never seen stuff like this before so i am not quite sure if this the correct way or not.

```
  +-------------------------------------------------
  |                                     |          |
+----+----------------+        +----+---------+----------+
|id  |module          |        |id  |child_id |parent_id |
+----+----------------+        +----+---------+----------+
|1   |node js         |        |1   | 3       | 1        |
+----+----------------+        +----+---------+----------+
|2   |python          |        |2   | 4       | 1        |
+----+----------------+        +----+---------+----------+
|3   |angular         |        |3   | 5       | 2        |
+----+----------------+        +----+---------+----------+
|4   |ionic           |        |4   | 6       | 2        |
+----+----------------+        +----+---------+----------+
|5   |tensorflow      |
+----+----------------+
|6   |jupyter notebook|
+----+----------------+
```

And hence i am confused how to solve this problem and i also happen to be a newbie and beginner. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self referring association will worked

```
module.associate = function(models) {
  Module.belongsTo(Module, {
    foreignKey: 'parent_id',
    as:'parent'
  })
};
```

Note that **we need** a `belongsTo` with `as` association and not a `hasMany`.

so the with the normal query

```
let modules = await models.Module.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: models.Module,
    as:'parent'
  }]
});
```

and it would result in the desired result

```
[{id: 1, module: 'node js', Module: []},
 {id: 2, module: 'python', Module: []},
 {id: 3, module: 'angular', Module: [
    {id: 1, module: 'node js'}
  ]},
 {id: 4, module: 'ionic', Module: [
    {id: 1, module: 'node js'},
  ]},
 {id: 5, module: 'tensorflow', Module: [
    {id: 2, module: 'python'},
  ]},
 {id: 6, module: 'jupyter notebook', Module: [
    {id: 2, module: 'python'},
  ]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a related many-to-many table like this:-

CREATE TABLE Language (
   lng_id INT NOT NULL,
   lng_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   Description VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
   Image BLOB NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (lng_id)

CREATE TABLE dependency_lng (
  lng_id1 INT NOT NULL, // FK related to language.lng_id
  lng_id2 INT NOT NULL), // FK related to language.lng_id
   CONSTRAINT pk_dependency_lng PRIMARY KEY (lng_id1, lng_id2)

You could add then as many entries as you want along side any Foreign keys if your requirement demands.

P.S :--- Also if you want,  auto incrementing column is not needed. The PRIMARY KEY can be (lng_id1,lng_id2)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you need a self referring association.

```
module.associate = function(models) {
    Module.hasMany(Module, {
      foreignKey: 'parent_id',
      as:'sub_entry'
    })
  };
```

Note that **you don't need** belongs to association and need to add keyword `as` for this association.

and your query

```
let modules = await models.Module.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: models.Module,
      as:'sub_entry'
    }]
```

Hope this would give what you expect. You don't need a auxiliary table for do this.

Comment: What ever you suggested is already happening as i have mentioned in my question, but that is not the desired result